# References to "purushartha" in vedas?

Tags: vedas

Are there any references to the word 'purushartha' in vedas?

Comment: There are four`Purushartha` as Dharma, Artha, Kama, and Moksha. So, do you want reference of these four or only the word Purushartha?

Comment: I am looking at slokas which tells there are "four purusharthas", and also explain what is the actual meaning of the word itself, If we take sandhi of the word Purushartha, we get Purusha + artha right?

Comment: Yes Purushartha is made up of two words Purusha+Artha which means purpose or goal of human being.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Suryopanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surya_Upanishad) is a minor Upanishad allied to the **Atharva Veda**.It has the word **Purushartha** in it.

> *aum atha sūryātharvāṅgirasam vyā̎khyāsyā̱maḥ | brahmā ṟṣih | gāya̍trī
>   chha̱ndaḥ | ādi̍tyo de̱vatā | haṁsa̍ḥ so̱’ham agni nārāyana yu̍ktam
>   bī̱jam | hrille̍khā śa̱ktiḥ | viyadādi sarga saṁyu̍ktaṁ kī̱lakam |
>   **catur-vidha puruṣārtha** siddhyarthe jape vi̍niyo̱gaḥ ||*

Meaning-

> Now   we  shall   expound mantras of  Atharva Veda    in  relation    to  the Sun:    The seer    of  this    Atharva Aṅgirasa
>   mantra    is  Brahma, metre   Gayatri,    Aditya  the deity,  ‘Hamsas so’ham  with    Agni    and Narayana    is  the seed,
>   the   power   is  hrillekha   or  hrim,   the pin is  the power   in  the process of  unfolding   the sky etc.,   the application 
>   is    its use in  repetition  for winning the four    human   goals   (viz.   Dharma, Artha,  Kama    and Mokṣa).

[image]

You can also read the Suryopanishad from [here](http://www.shrisuryanarayanmandir.org/documents/SURYOPANISHAT.pdf).

**Note for Suresh**-I have assumed that you wanted the references from any **Sruti texts**(Vedas,Upanishads ).But,if you want specifically from the **Vedas only** then i need to delete my answer.Hence,waiting for your response.

**An update**-We also find mention of the **Chaturvida Purusharthas** (viz Dharma,artha,kama & moksha) in another minor Upanishad text called the  [Ganapty Atharvashrisha Upanishad](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_ganesha-ganapati_atharvashirsha.php)

> सायमधीयानो दिवसकृतं पापं नाशयति । प्रातरधीयानो रात्रिकृतं पापं नाशयति
>   । सायं प्रातः प्रयुञ्जानो पापोऽपापो भवति । सर्वत्राधीयानोऽपविघ्नो भवति
>   । **धर्मार्थकाममोक्षं** च विन्दति ॥१३॥

This is verse no. 13 with meanings as given below:

> 13.5: Studying this in the Evening will destroy the Sins committed during the Day (including the tendency to commit Sins),
>   13.6: Studying this in the Morning will destroy the Sins committed during the Night (including the tendency to commit Sins),
>   13.7: Joining (the Study and Deep Contemplation) both in the Evening and Morning, will make a Sinful person Sinless (by gradually revealing
>   the deeper consciousness and thereby removing the tendencies to commit
>   Sins),
>   13.8: Studying everywhere (i.e. in all situations) will remove the Obstacles, ...
>   13.9: ... (And) **the Devotee will obtain Dharma, Artha (Prosperity), Kama (Right Desires fulfilled) and (finally) Moksha (Liberation by
>   discovering the deeper consciousness)**,

Comment: Thank you very much, I meant Sruti only, not specific to any vedas. This is what i was looking for, but surprised could not find many references. Would be great if you could add more references.

Comment: @suresh Ok & you are welcome..yes i'll be on the look out for more such references....